# Unable to install other office applications after installing Office Suite from an Office365 License

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office

I have installed the Office Suite from my subscription I have through my email subscription with Office 365. I have Visio/Project 2016 as stand alone versions I would like to install and use but I get the following error:

[image]

Does this mean I need to use a different version of Office? I remember days when installing and using Microsoft products were so much easier..

EDIT: I tried both 64bit and 32bit. I get the same error but it just shows the same error but with 64 and 32 inverted.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Office apps come in two flavors: 32-bit and 64-bit. (The 32-bit flavor is stuck under the 4 GB RAM limit.)

You can identify your flavor of Office using its About... dialog box found on the "Account" tab of the backstage view.

[image: Screenshot of About... dialog box for Microsoft Word 2013 64-bit]

**Here is the catch:** Once you installed a single Office app, every other Office apps that you install afterward must have the same flavor. You see in this image that I have installed Word 2013 64-bit. I will not be able to install Visio 32-bit. But Visio 64-bit installs okay.

Comment: Correct. Additionally, most people should just stick with the 32-bit version. Except for extremely rare or contrived very large documents, you just don't need the RAM from 64-bit, but going to 64-bit can create real compatibility issues with some older files and plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove just that component and that will allow you to install the correct 32/64 bit of the office application (in my own experience - Office 2013, and Project 2016).

**CAVEAT:** At the moment I'm not 100% sure what is the possible backlash of doing this, but I know have done it, and it works and I am able to install Project 2016 32 bit, alongside Office 2013 32 bit.

The steps are:

1. Go to Start > Run (or Winkey + R)
2. Type “installer” (that opens the %windir%installer folder), make sure all files are visible in Windows (Folder Settings)
3. Add the column “Subject” (and make it at least 400 pixels wide) – Right click on the column headers, click More, then find Subject
4. Sort on the Subject column and scroll down until you locate the name mentioned in your error screen (“Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component ”) - choose either 32 or 64 accordingly - depends on what is stopping you.
5. Right click the MSI and choose uninstall
6. Try installing again.

Credit from https://www.tecklyfe.com/fix-for-microsoft-office-setup-error-please-uninstall-all-32-bit-office-programs-office-15-click-to-run-extensibility-component/

Comment: **Very** dangerous answer! Mustn't one try the ordinary avenue of _Programs and Features_ in the Control Panel first before galavanting into Windows installers cache? Besides, these instructions are for Office 2013, not 2016.

Comment: It is not there. I have looked and it was bugging me for long time. Yes the instruction was for office 2013 but the one I had removed is office 16 which is for office 2016. I had adjusted the instruction as needed based on my condition. As I said at my caveat - I'm not 100% sure what backlash it will have but my own anecdotal evidence - it works - and I have applied it to several PCs in succession and it works for them. In my case particular case I had to even remove Microsoft database engine 2010 which was also preventing installation using the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Installing another version that was not Office 365 based fixed the issue.